# Meaning of noun + らっけかぁ～

Tags: slang, colloquial-language

This bolded sentence is from Persona 4, from a random stranger:

> 酔っ払い上司：ガハハ！
>
> 何だお前、噂の幽霊が怖いのかぁ！？
>
> **夜中、神社に立って魚を欲しがる白い着物の幽霊らっけかぁ～？**
>
> そんなんガキが夜遊びする為の嘘っぱちに決まってんらろぉ～！

([transcript with this sentence](http://p4g.janken-pon.net/june/605ysh))

What does the last part, 幽霊らっけかぁ～, mean? Is this slang?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This person's drunk and his speech's slurred. He's trying to say 白い着物の幽霊だってかぁ～？

This ダ行→ラ行 sound change is commonly seen in drunken speech.

> 決まってん**だ**ろ～！ → 決まってん**ら**ろぉ～！
>
> XXです。→ XXれす。
>   XXだよ。→ XXらよ。

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer! Makes sense now that you clarified it