# Meaning of らいじょうぶ

Tags: slang, manga, japanese-to-english

I am reading a manga and found this:

> A : あんなに吞んで大丈夫なの？
>
> B : ***らいじょぶ...***

The character is drunk so is this a slurred **大丈夫**？

*It has been a long time since I posted here, the updates are awesome!*

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23543/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,that’s right!
It means だいじょうぶ.

Comment: Is this sound change from だ to ら a common thing when denoting drunken speech?

Comment: Yes!
And there are some other expressions like these...
1.だいじょぶ
2.らいじょぶ
I guess what the expression will the author choose is depends on how to express character's personality in the Manga story so it is difficult to express the reason why these expressions for foreign country people...
But you can understand this expressions nuance so that's nice!!