# Meaning of "らめえ"

Tags: meaning, translation

[image]

I already search for it on Jisho, but I was not be able to find the meaning of this "らめえ" thing. Could someone help me?

Edit: about the context, it was a rich teenager girl who was talking to her servant in a group meeting. Since she was saying something about "today" and "miss" (title), and by her facial expression, she was probably denying the action of her servant calling her "さま" in that day, probably wanting to hide the fact that he is her servant. Even so らめえ was probably denying something in that context, I didn't get it's true meaning.

Obs: she was not drunk.

Comment: Could you give more context about where/ the situation in which this was said?

Comment: This sounds like "drunk talk" for だめ, but it's not fully clear to me. More context would be desirable.

Comment: Context includes the actual conversation leading up to this line. It helps us understand exactly what this is a response to. Outside of that, this sounds like the trope used in adult materials for だめ while having an orgasm, but it feels out of place with this line alone, so I don't want to jump the gun.

Comment: Reference for drunken speech: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23543/meaning-of-noun-%e3%82%89%e3%81%a3%e3%81%91%e3%81%8b%e3%81%81%ef%bd%9e/23544#23544

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen the "らめぇ!" translated into English as "Ron't!".
The word "らめぇ!" is a lispy way of saying  "だめ". (to cannot speak clearly / ろれつが回らない状態).
It is used to joke around a little, and is used for hedonic or infantile expressions. It is slang for a subculture.

[「らめぇ」とは？！意味を解説](https://meaning-book.com/blog/20191122144353.html)

---

I'm not an expert, so I don't know, but some people have said the following.

> まともな人間なので、「らめぇ」が英語で「Ron't…」と訳されているという事実に言及し、これは言語学的には/t, d, n, s, z/などの歯茎位置を使う子音の閉鎖や狭めが弱まってより緩い歯茎音の/r/に至る自然な現象でありR-18表現に使われるのは示唆的であると説明しておく。
> [Twitter / anima_solaris (via spindrift64)](https://minbow3.tumblr.com/post/165539913709/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E4%BA%BA%E9%96%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%82%89%E3%82%81%E3%81%87%E3%81%8C%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7ront%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E4%BA%8B%E5%AE%9F%E3%81%AB%E8%A8%80%E5%8F%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E5%AD%A6%E7%9A%84)

> Ron't：成人漫画などで見かける「らめぇ」（「だめぇ」の舌足らずな風な発音を表現）を訳したもの（Don't→Ron't）。ただし、本当にこうした語が作られていたのか疑問視する声もある(らめぇ！は本当にRon't!と略されていたのか問題 : lowlevelaware)。海外の情報源発見できず。
> [【メモ用】HENTAI用語集](https://shijimi-no-misoshiru.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/17/175700)

Answer (score 1):

I searched らめぇ on Google and the first few links all explain it as meaning だめ or やめろ, which seems to make sense in this context right?

https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%89%E3%82%81%E3%81%87

https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%89%E3%82%81%E3%81%87